# Batch file: How to set a variable to a single space

Tags: batch-file, variables, alignment, character

I would like to know how to set a batch file variable to a single space character. (I'm not talking about spaces inside a variable, such as a file name, but just a single space.)

**The problem:** I have a series of echo commands where I want to align 3 columns of text across multiple lines. The desired outcome should be something like this:

```
Code  Yes-No  Description of option
----  ------  ----------------------------
  N     Yes   This option includes Series N machines
  P     No    This option includes Series P and Series P5 machines
  X     --    Exit this process
```

- Column 1 consists of a single letter. Each row has a different letter.
- Column 2 has several variables ("Selection_N" and "Selection_P"), each either "Yes" or "No", one per row. As multiple selections are permitted, any combination of Yes and No is permitted.
- Column 3 is text of variable length. Each row has different text. The problem comes in aligning column 3 whether column 2 is Yes or No.

Code (somewhere else in the batch file) sets "Selection_N" and "Selection_P" variables to either Yes or No. That is:

```
if SomeCondition (Set Selection_N=Yes) else (Set Selection_N=No)
if AnotherCondition (Set Selection_P=Yes) else (Set Selection_P=No)
```

Then in the user interface portion of the batch file, the current option selection is displayed:

```
echo Code  Yes-No  Description of option
echo ----  ------  ----------------------------
echo  N     %Selection_N%   This option includes Series N machines
echo  P     %Selection_P%   This option includes Series P and Series P5 machines
echo  X     --    Exit this process
```

My approach so far has been to try to modify the variables in the second column so that 3 characters are always displayed, which then aligns column 3.

**So far I've tried:**

- Using quote marks and set the variable to either "Yes" or "No " -- but the quote marks echo.
- Using a trailing space and set the variable to either Yes or No§ (where "§" is actually a space), but the trailing space is ignored.
- Adding another variable (XSpace) set to either nothing or to a single space, then trying to echo %Selection_P%%XSpace% -- but this ends up having the same problems as the first two solutions.
- Adding another variable (XSpace) set to either nothing or to an "unobtrusive" character like a backtick (`), then echoing %Selection_P%%XSpace% -- this works but is ugly.
- Changing the third column text into a variable and adding an extra space to the start of the variable value based on the value of Selection_N. This works, but is cumbersome. For something as simple as this illustrative example I would accept it, but the actual batch file is more complex and I would like a simpler solution.

I'm hoping for a simple and elegant way to do something like

```
Set XSpace=Blah
```

Where "Blah" evaluates to a single space when used in an echo command like this:

```
echo  N     %Selection_N%%Blah%   This option includes Series N machines
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The typical approach is to define the variable with a trailing spaces and using substring modification to output the first n desired characters. IE: `Echo(%varname:~0,3%` When assigning variable values, use doublequotes to either protect against undesired spaces or to clearly mark their inclusion: `Set "Varname=somestring "`

Comment: This worked. SET "XSpace= " or SET XSpace= to give me one space or none, respectively. Thanks!

Comment: `if SomeCondition (Set "Selection_N=Yes") else (Set "Selection_N=No ")` ?

Comment: Also, please left align your columnar data, with no leading spaces. Not only can I not think of any decent program which does that, it looks cheap and childish, and could make future parsing of the data more difficult.

Comment: Compo, not sure of your meaning. If you are referring to my initial desired outcome, I suppose it's "different strokes for different folks" -- personally I think the display is fairly elegant given the limitations of fixed fonts in a command window. If, however, you are referring to something else, I'm all ears. Thanks for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Per T3RROR's comment, the code that works is:

```
if SomeCondition (Set "XSpace_N= ") else (Set XSpace_N=)
if AnotherCondition (Set "XSpace_P= ") else (Set XSpace_P=)
---
echo Code  Yes-No  Description of option
echo ----  ------  ----------------------------
echo  N     %Selection_N%%XSpace_N%   This option includes Series N machines
echo  P     %Selection_P%%XSpace_P%   This option includes Series P and Series P5 machines
echo  X     --    Exit this process
```

The key is enclosing the entire varstring=something in quotes, not just the assigned characters. Thanks, T3RROR :-)